# Implementing specific distribution in python

Tags: python, random, probability

i want to return `1<l<10` with probability `1/(2^(l-1))`

how i should do this rather then:

```py
    x = random()
    if x < 0.5:
       return 2
```

and so on

thank you

Comment: Please specify if you mean discrete or continuous distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be fun...  I am a bit rusty with these things, so a good matematician could fix my reasoning.

To generate a distribution from a formula you need first to do some integrals and calculate the cumulative density function for the specified interval.
In particular we need to start to calculate the normalization constant.
[image: Compute normalization constant]

This integral gives, for "k":

[image: k value]

The "meaning" of the cumulative density function is "what's the probability to obtain a certain number that belong to the interval I need?". This question can be seen in another way: "the probability to take a number that is below or equal to 10 must be 1". This lead to the following equation that help to to find the parameter "C".  Note that the first therm is the k, the second therm is the general integral of 2^(1-x) where I have replace x with 10.
[image: Almost full CDF]

Solving this we finally reach the CDF (again, it is possible that the way to find it is easier):

[image: Final CDF]

At this point we need to reverse the CDF for X.  X is now our random number generator between 0 and 1.  The formula is:
[image: random values distributed with the asked law]

In python code I tried the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=[ 1-   np.log2(1-(1-2**(-9))*np.random.rand()) for i in range(10000)]

plt.hist(a, normed=True)
```

[image]

Does it makes sense?

Comment: Bumping you for a lot of effort, and it might be right, but truncated exponential (this is what it is, really) is already implemented in Python ecosystem, take a look at my answer

Comment: True and true.  On the other side, my line of reasoning could be generalized to almost any function.  So another programmer could follow my reasoning to find a generator for the function he wants. But indeed, your solution is simpler. A question though, PDF(x)~2^-x is an approximation not very good for x~1 since his function is PDF(x)~2^(1-x).  I see a bit of difference on the first bin between my histogram and your, is it due to that? +1 to your answer

Comment: Thanks. In histogram you have 10 bins and I have 9

Answer (score 1):

While @Fabrizio answer is probably true, there is a lot simpler way to get job done - what you want is truncated exponential, because your PDF looks like

PDF(x) ~ 2<sup>-x</sup> = e<sup>-x log(2)</sup>.

There is already truncated exponential in the SciPy, take a look [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncexpon.html).

Just set proper scale and location, and job is done. Code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import truncexpon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vmin = 1.0
vmax = 10.0
scale=1.0/np.log(2.0)

r = truncexpon.rvs(b=(vmax-vmin)/scale, loc=vmin, scale=scale, size=100000)

print(np.min(r))
print(np.max(r))

plt.hist(r, bins=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], density=True)
```

Histogram

[image]

And if you need to sample only integer values, there is good helper function in Numpy as well, code below, graph is quite similar

```
#%%
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vmin = 1
vmax = 10

v = np.arange(vmin+1, vmax, dtype=np.int64)
p  = np.asarray([1.0/2**(l-1) for l in range(vmin+1, vmax)]) # probabilities
p /= np.sum(p) # normalization

r = np.random.choice(v, size=100000, replace=True, p=p)

print(np.min(r))
print(np.max(r))

plt.hist(r, bins=[1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5], density=True)
```