# Monte Carlo method for Gaussian distribution with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, statistics, montecarlo

I am trying to implement Monte Carlo method for Gaussian to approximate cdf. but it's not working. I'm trying to approximate from x = 0 to x = inf but I thought 1000 is good enough. it should give me an answer close to one.

```
from scipy import random
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np


def guassian_approx(mean, var):
    sd = var**0.5 
    n=10000;
    a = 0;
    b = 1000
    x = random.uniform(-1000, 1000, n)
    sm = norm(mean, sd).pdf(x)
    p = (b-a) * np.mean(sm)   
    return p
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track. You can help others help you by explaining more about what you're trying to accomplish, what result you expected, and what result you actually got. By the way, think about how the accuracy of Monte Carlo varies with `n`. How does the result change if you try `n` = 100, 10000, 1000000 ?

Comment: @RobertDodier this implementation gives me an answer of 0.4 although it should give me 1. (with current values). I know increasing n would better approximate the average of function. I'm trying this with mean=3 and standard deviation= 1.

Comment: A couple of things. (1) Don't you want to choose x on the range (a, b)? (2) If the range (a, b) is much wider than mean +/- a few multiples of sd, then most of the points have pdf = approximately 0, and don't contribute. So the effective number of points is much less than `n`. Maybe you should make the range (a, b) smaller, or choose a and b according to mean and sd.

Comment: @RobertDodier yep, that was my mistake, using smaller values for x and a,b gives much better approximation. Thanks.

Comment: Hello check also this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625669/implementing-specific-distribution-in-python/58627931#58627931